# How can I use simian clone detection tool?

Tags: clone

How can I use simian clone detection tool? Can anyone help me, please?
-Saidur

Answer (score 4):

Here is the script we're using:

```
DEL /s /f /q simian.xml
D:\Simian\simian.exe -formatter=xml:simian.xml -includes=**\*.cs -excludes=**\*.Generated.cs -excludes=**\*.g.cs -excludes=**\*.Designer.cs "-excludes=**\Service References\**\*.cs" -excludes=**\*Tests.cs
exit 0
```